# Get Option tag value in php

Tags: php, html, ajax, magento

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2

```
<div id="display">
    <?php 
        if (sizeof($final_na)>0) { 
            $i = 0;
        ?>
        <select size="5" class="auto-search" style="height:132px;width: 420px;padding:0px;" name="hero">
            <?php foreach ($final_na as $key => $value) { ?>
                <option style="text-align:center;padding: 5px 0 0;" value="<?php echo $final_na1[$i]; ?>" class="display_box" align="left" onclick="fill('<?php echo $value;?>')">
                    <?php echo $value; ?>
                </option>
                <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
    <label for="description" class="rightgap"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('Description') ?> :</label>
    <textarea name="description" class="required-entry " id="description" rows="5" cols="75" ><?php echo $description?></textarea>

    <label for="price" class="rightgap"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('Price') ?> :</label>
    <input type="price" class=" required-entry widthinput" name="price" id="price" value="<?php echo $price?>"/>
```

here i'm displaying a dropdown,based on my selection from this dropdown have to fill the remaining fields have to fill.

for example selected option value is 25 this is product id in my site based on that id values have to fill below like description,price....

for this i have to get that option value in one variable...

Using this script i'm getting the selected option value

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#display').click(function(){ 
                var searchbox = $("#display :selected").val();
                alert(searchbox);
            });
        });
</script>
```

but i can't store it in a variable in php

Any ideas ?

Comment: I have to store that Selected value in a variable in php

Comment: If you have a `<form>` around the `<select>` you can submit the form with a `<input type='submit' name='save' value='save'>` the value will be accessible in php via `$_POST['hero']`. Alternatively you can send it via ajax to php from your click function.

Comment: No i have submit button after some more fields if i use submit button it'll not make sense.  And form also i have before this any way i have to get this dynamically

Answer (score 0):

you can send the value of searchbox via json to targetfile.php
inside your click handler

```
$.ajax({
      url: "targetfile.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType : "json",
      data: {"hero":searchbox},
      success: function(data) { 
         // something that should happen after success
         // data is filled with the output of targetfile.php (should be json)
      }
});
```

do `print_r($_POST);` in targetfile.php to see what you get. 
And take a look at the Console tab of firebug.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I don't have any target file... i have only one file.

Comment: however, you need a file to handle the request. If you have only one you have the option to modify it to answer the request proper or create a new one to handle the request.